# Como mostrar los días que no tienen registros en MySQL y dales un valor en el resultado de la querry

Tags: mysql

mi idea es coger los datos de una tabla en al cual si falta un día los valores de títulos valdrán titulo='NULL' y color='RED'.
Muestro mas detalle para que se entienda mas:

Yo tengo una tabla con lo siguientes valores;

[image]

^^Aqui se puede ver que entre el registro 4 y 5 faltaría un registro mas^^

Bien pues lo que yo quiero es que me al yo hacer un select con MySQL lo que me muestre sea los 6 registros y entre el 4 y el 5 un registro que muestre :
Fechainicio='2021-12-01 12:45:39',Fechafin='2021-12-02 12:45:38', titulo='NULL', color='RED'.

pero sin que me edite la tabla, es decir no me initeresa hacer inserts ni updates.

cosnulta inicial"

```
SELECT c.titulo, c.fechaINICIO, c.fechaFIN, c.COLOR,T.*, IFNULL(c.color, 'RED') AS color,IFNULL(c.titulo, 'NULL')AS PID FROM calendario c right JOIN
(select concat(a.Date, ' ',h.ini) AS ini, concat(a.Date, ' ',h.fechaFIN) AS fin
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
) a, (SELECT '6:00' AS ini, '8:00' AS fin UNION ALL SELECT '8:00' AS ini, '14:00' AS fin UNION ALL SELECT '14:00' AS ini, '22:00' AS fin UNION ALL SELECT '22:00' AS ini, '6:00' AS fin)  h
where a.Date between '2021-01-01' AND CURDATE()) t
on c.fechaINICIO BETWEEN t.ini AND t.fechafin;
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir la consulta original que estás haciendo? ¿La hora `12:45:38` es arbitraria o tiene algún sentido o significado?

Comment: @OscarGarcia acabo de editar la pregunta al final puedes ver la querry, aunque es de otra tabla(vendría a ser la tabla original), sobre el tema de la hora quisiera hacer lo miso ya no solo poner un nul con la fecha, sino que si entre horas del mismo día no hay un registro poner un null

Comment: Creo que tras la edición me has liado aún más. ¿Podrías poner datos de ejemplo y lo que esperas obtener? En esa consulta SQL hay campos que no salen en tu captura y usas un rango de fechas hasta 9999 días atrás (así, a bote pronto, aunque luego filtras a los que sean desde comienzo de año hasta el día en curso) y solo con rangos de 8:00 a 14:00. ¿Podrías limpiar la pregunta dejando el esquema de la tabla (usa `SHOW CREATE TABLE tu_tabla` para obtener la definición) y la consulta que quieres adaptar con relleno de fechas.

Comment: @OscarGarcia podrias mirar si ahora lo entiendes mejor?